# Hyperref does not place anchor at the right place

Tags: hyperref, report

The following modification of the report class definitions of the `makechapterhead` and `makeschapterhead` does not play well with the hyperref package. In particular, clicking on the bookmarks does not get to the right place.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter 

\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]
{\vspace*{-40\p@}
 {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
 \hrule                                 
 \vspace{5pt}                           
 \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \LARGE\scshape {{\bfseries\@chapapp\space \thechapter}
         \par\nobreak
         \vskip 5\p@
         \fi
             \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Large\scshape #1\par   
                } 
 \vspace{5pt}                           
 \hrule                                 
 \nobreak
 \vskip 40\p@
 }
}


\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]
{\vspace*{-40\p@}
 {\parindent \z@ \raggedright\normalfont
 \hrule 
 \vspace{5pt}
 \interlinepenalty\@M
 \Large\scshape{#1\par}
 \vspace{5pt}
 \hrule
 \nobreak
 \vskip 40\p@
 }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Preamble}
\chapter*{Preamble}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Preface}
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Introduction} 
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.